# can there be more than one height balanced BST with same inorder traversal?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I was solving [this](https://www.interviewbit.com/old/problems/sorted-array-to-balanced-bst/) problem and I am confused if there can be multiple answers to one input.

Comment: Please include the full text of the question in the question, rather than referring to an outside link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; if not all leaves have the same depth, you can basically decide where to leave nodes out (subject to some restrictions). This is the case, if the number of nodes of the tree cannot be expressed as `2^n-1` for an integer `n` (`^` being exponentiation in this case).  Let's assume we've got elements 1 to 6:

Possible trees

```
      4
   /    \
  2      5
 / \      \
1   3      6
```

```
      4
   /    \
  2      6
 / \    /
1   3  5
```

```
      3
   /    \
  2      5
 /      / \
1      4   6
```

```
      3
   /    \
  1      5
   \    / \
    2  4   6
```

Answer (score 0):

### Case of the perfect binary tree

If the number of elements in the array is exactly "a power of two minus one", such as 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, etc, then it's relatively easy to prove that there can be only one balanced binary search tree with the same inorder traversal. Indeed, the left and right subtrees will need to have the same number of elements; therefore the root must be the median element; and by induction there is only one possibility for the right subtree and for the left subtree.

For instance, this is the only complete binary search tree using elements `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`:

```
     4
   /   \
  2     6
 / \   / \ 
1   3 5   7
```

### Case of the imperfect binary tree

If the number of elements in the array is not exactly "a power of two minus one", then the tree will not be perfect; in particular, there will be two possible depths for the leaves. This gives us a bit of slack that we can use to produce multiple solutions.

For instance, these are four trees using elements `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`:

```
   3             3             4             4
 /   \         /   \         /   \         /   \
1     5       2     5       2     5       2     6
 \   / \     /     / \     / \     \     / \   /  
  2 4   6   1     4   6   1   3     6   1   3 5
```